# How to get Drush to be able to query the DB?

Tags: drush

I am getting the following error trying to run Drush on Win10, WSL2, and DDev. I can run other Drush commands, but not all of them.

How do I fix it?

```
Command self-update was not found. Drush was unable to query the database. 
As a result, many commands are unavailable. 
Re-run your command with --debug to see relevant log messages.
```

Below is the output when I run the command with the debug flag...

```
username@DESKTOP-4JKF77A:~/workspace/drupal8Dev$ drush self-update --debug
[preflight] Config paths: /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
[preflight] Alias paths: /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/web/drush/sites,/home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/drush/sites
[preflight] Commandfile search paths: /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/vendor/drush/drush/src
[debug] Bootstrap further to find self-update [0.03 sec, 7.94 MB]
[debug] Trying to bootstrap as far as we can [0.03 sec, 7.94 MB]
[debug] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot() [0.03 sec, 7.94 MB]
[debug] Change working directory to /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/web [0.03 sec, 7.94 MB]
[debug] Initialized Drupal 8.9.7 root directory at /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/web [0.03 sec, 8.14 MB]
[debug] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite() [0.03 sec, 8.43 MB]
[debug] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.04 sec, 8.67 MB]
[debug] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalConfiguration() [0.04 sec, 8.66 MB]
[debug] Add service modifier [0.04 sec, 8.79 MB]
[debug] Unable to connect to database. More information may be available by running `drush status`. 
This may occur when Drush is trying to bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database.
In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line.
See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details. [0.04 sec, 8.84 MB]
[debug] Bootstrap phase bootstrapDrupalDatabase() failed to validate; continuing at bootstrapDrupalConfiguration() [0.04 sec, 8.84 MB]
[debug] Done with bootstrap max in Application::bootstrapAndFind(): trying to find self-update again. [0.04 sec, 8.84 MB]

In Application.php line 239:

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
Command self-update was not found. Drush was unable to query the database. As a result, many commands are 
unavailable. Re-run your command with --debug to see relevant log messages.


Exception trace:
at /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/vendor/drush/drush/src/Application.php:239
Drush\Application->bootstrapAndFind() at /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/vendor/drush/drush/src/Application.php:192
Drush\Application->find() at /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:236
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:118
Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:49
Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:72
require() at /home/username/workspace/drupal8Dev/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4
```

Comment: You should probably ask this question on Stack Overflow, having it tagged `ddev`. The maintainers normally react pretty fast there.

Comment: How exactly did you run the command? `ddev exec 'drush COMMAND'`? Or with the new `ddev drush COMMAND`?

Comment: And did you `export IS_DDEV_PROJECT=true`? At least this needed to happen on Mac to run Drush Launcher and be able to simply `drush COMMAND` from outside as usual.

Comment: Looks like the database connection is not set right in sites/default/settings.php
Does the site function at all?

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk Yes, the site works correctly.

Comment: @leymannx, I think that was my issue. I wasn't adding 'ddev exec' before the drush command.

Comment: This issue is a bit outdated. You should now install Drush using Composer, and update with Composer